# SQL select unique items from everyone's desk

Tags: sql

I have a [SQL database: 3 desks, and what they contain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdbzE.png)
and I need to extract only the items that are unique on each desk and the desk the items are on.
The task looks disturbingly easy but my brain can't comprehend the extra SQL commands, therefore I have 0 idea how I could get the answer for the question.

A code I created was:

```
SELECT WhoseDesk, Item, count(Item) as found_nr 
FROM [Office] 
GROUP BY Item,WhoseDesk 
HAVING count(Item)=1 
ORDER BY found_nr, WhoseDesk,Item
```

The answer I got

[image]

The answer should be

[image]

Ty kind stranger for helping me out.

Comment: Add editable datas for sample not images. ([https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: GROUP BY item alone. Use max/min to get its desk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this query for searching items that are on the desk and not on the other desk:

```
select *
from [Office] [outer]
where not exists( select 1 from [Office] 
                  where Item = [outer].Item
                  and WhoseDesk <> [outer].WhoseDesk )
```

Comment: This did the trick. Thank you so much!